# Apache Spark Loading ALS Model : Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an ALS model and saved it with these code:

```
            als_path = "saved_models/best"
            best_model.save(sc, path= als_path)
```

However when I try to load this model, it gives this error message:

```
---> 10 model2 = ALS.load(als_path)

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py:332, in MLReadable.load(cls, path)
    329 @classmethod
    330 def load(cls, path):
    331     """Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read().load(path)`."""
--> 332     return cls.read().load(path)

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py:282, in JavaMLReader.load(self, path)
    280 if not isinstance(path, str):
    281     raise TypeError("path should be a string, got type %s" % type(path))
--> 282 java_obj = self._jread.load(path)
    283 if not hasattr(self._clazz, "_from_java"):
    284     raise NotImplementedError("This Java ML type cannot be loaded into Python currently: %r"
    285                               % self._clazz)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o372.load.
: org.json4s.MappingException: Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
    at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:53)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.$anonfun$convert$2(Extraction.scala:881)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.convert(Extraction.scala:881)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.$anonfun$extract$10(Extraction.scala:456)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.$anonfun$customOrElse$1(Extraction.scala:780)
```

I both tried to use `ALS.load` or `ALSModel.load` as shown in the Apache spark documentation: [https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS.html#:~:text=als_path%20%3D%20temp_path%20%2B%20%22/als%22%0A%3E%3E%3E](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS.html#:%7E:text=als_path%20%3D%20temp_path%20%2B%20%22/als%22%0A%3E%3E%3E)

Note: I looked at other similar errors asked in StackOverflow, but there was no solution for my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this, works for me

```
als_path = "saved_models/best"
best_model.save(sc, als_path)

ALS = best_model.load(als_path)
```

Comment: But my goal is not to train again and again...Otherwise, I can use best_model directly